# On a North American bus or subway, what do you call the long horizontal ads on the tops of the "walls"?

Tags: nouns

Is there an official term for the ads that you see on public transit *inside* the vehicle or car, *above* the windows/doors, long horizontal panels, usually about 24" x /12"?

Comment: Perhaps you have a picture of one?  I am only thinking of horizontal ads...

Comment: Are these on the inside of the subway cars, on the outside of the subway cars, on walls in the subway tunnels, or in the subway stations? I've seen ads all these places? I don't know if any of them have special names.

Comment: Good question, Peter, I've edited the original question for more clarity. I'm talking about ads that are inside the subway or bus. I'm hoping somebody may know if there's a special term for them or if they're just "interior high-up vertical panel ads".

Comment: [This website](http://www.bluelinemedia.com/subway-advertising) calls it "interior display (horizontal format)". I expect you were looking for something less prosaic.

Comment: I'd just refer to them as "ads in the bus" or "on the subway/el/T/Tube...". There's no term that specifically distinguishes ads inside a subway car from those in the tunnels or stations. Though of course advertisers will have their own jargon in their own speech community, like any other.

Comment: Here in Broward County (Fort Lauderdale, FL, USA) they are called "interior placards" by the transit system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interior cards 
 Rail Cards and Behind-The-Driver Posters

The Rail Cards line both sides of the bus interior above the windows, and the BTD Poster is positioned on the divider that separates the driver from the passenger seating.

http://www.oaaa.org/outofhomeadvertising/oohmediaformats/railsystemssubways.aspx